# How can I use `cabal repl` instead of `ghci` in `ghc-mod`?

Tags: haskell, emacs, cabal, emacs24, ghc-mod

I want to use cabal repl to instead of ghci (. My goal is being able to use other modules in my project ).

Comment: https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My setups uses this:

```
(setq haskell-program-name "cabal repl")
(setq haskell-ghci-program-name "cabal repl")
(custom-set-variables
 ;; ...
 '(haskell-process-type 'cabal-repl)
 ;; ...
)
```

concerning ghc and cabal and is running fine as it is (current ghc-mod and emacs  24.3.1)

Answer (score 4):

GHC-mod has [an issue](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues/171) about this, where the author suggests changing the GHCi executable:

```
(setq haskell-ghci-program-name "cabal")
(setq haskell-ghci-program-args '("repl"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should consider to setup [Haskell Interactive Mode](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/wiki/Haskell-Interactive-Mode-Setup).

Unlike Inferior Haskell Mode, this mode is deeply integrated into Cabal.  It does not only use `cabal repl`, but also interprets Cabal error messages and suggests to add imports or language extensions, and provides completion for modules.